# Can I run a bash script that is located on my local machine on a remote server?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have local scripts that I would like to run on a remote server. I have already set up ssh key pairs to enable login without a password.

My current approach is to rsync the script to the server and then run it:

```
ssh user@remoteserver "rsync localserver:script.sh ./; ./script.sh; rm script.sh"
```

However, this seems like a hack; Is there a more user friendly way to do this?

update: since there are so many good answers, can anyone help me select the 'best' one by providing rationale?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SSH will take commands from `stdin`

```
ssh -T user@server <script.sh
```

**edit**: `-T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation`

Comment: nice! just what I want except that it returns "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."; do you know why or how I can get rid of this?

Comment: Hi eduffy, can I do this but send parameters, e.g. instead of running script.sh 1 2 on the server, send ssh -T user@server < script.sh 4 10 (except that this doesn't work). -thansk

Answer (score 3):

There is always a way.

```
ssh user@host 'sh -' < script.sh
```

Comment: great. this takes care of the error message returned by not using the 'sh -'... do you know why?

Comment: I cannot in all confidence tell you precisely what the differences are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using pipes:

Test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "test"
```

Pipe to bash on remote machine:

```
ajw@xxxxxxx:/tmp > cat test.sh | ssh ajw@xxxxxxxx.xxx.xx "cat | bash"
test
```

Comment: @Sorpigal, what do you mean by unnecessary?

Comment: The "cat | bash" can be replaced with "bash -" and the "cat test.sh" can be implemented with < as in Sorpigal's answer.

Answer (score 1):

another version of the answer by @Sorpigal

```
ssh user@host 'bash -s' < script.sh
```

Comment: `'bash -'` would also work, though -s seems like it's designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -T user@server < script.sh
# "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."
```

You are confusing the `sshd` server since it assumes an interactive login session with stdin being a terminal - `sshd` would allocate a pseudo-tty for such a session - if **no** command is specified as an argument to your `ssh` (client) command, but instead `sshd` sees the stdin of its default shell being redirected from the file specified by the input redirection operator `<`.

It's kind of unexpected behaviour from `sshd`'s point of view when the `ssh` client does not provide a command to be executed on the remote host but redirects the stdin of `sshd`'s default shell from a file or here document / string or pipe.

```
ssh localhost <<<'echo Hello, world!'
ssh localhost sh <<<'echo Hello, world!'
ssh -T localhost <<<'echo Hello, world!'
```