# How can I execute a script from my local machine in a specific (but variable) directory on a remote host?

Tags: bash, ssh

From  a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089898/199217), I have found that it is possible to run a local script on a remote host using:

```
ssh -T remotehost < localscript.sh
```

Now, I need to allow others to specify the directory in which the script will be run on the remote host.

I have tried commands such as

```
 ssh -T remotehost "cd /path/to/dir" < localscript.sh
 ssh -T remotehost:/path/to/dir < localscript.sh
```

and I have even tried adding `DIR=$1; cd $DIR` to the script and using

```
 ssh -T remotehost < localscript.sh "/path/to/dir/"
```

alas, none of these work. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: your question belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 'cd /path/to/dir' | cat - localscript.sh | ssh -T remotehost
```

Note that if you're doing this for anything complex, it is very, very important that you think carefully about how you will handle errors in the remote system.  It is very easy to write code that works just fine as long as the stars align.  What is much harder - and often very necessary - is to write code that will provide useful debugging messages if stuff breaks for any reason.

Also you may want to look at the venerable tool http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect.  It is often used for scripting things on remote machines.  (And yes, error handling is a long term maintenance issue with it.)

Comment: thanks! that works nicely, and thanks for the tips - I keep log files on the remote server that I check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Two more ways to change directory on the remote host (variably):

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
cd "$1" || exit 1
pwd -P
shift
printf "%s\n" "$@" | cat -n
exit
' > localscript.sh

ssh localhost 'bash -s "$@"' <localscript.sh '/tmp' 2 3 4 5 
ssh localhost 'source /dev/stdin "$@"' <localscript.sh '/tmp' 2 3 4 5 

# make sure it's the bash shell to source & execute the commands
#ssh -T localhost 'bash -c '\''source /dev/stdin "$@"'\''' _ <localscript.sh '/tmp' 2 3 4 5
```